# Increment alphabetical string in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, function, ruby-on-rails-3, each, alphabet

***Task I want to solve:***

*Write a program that takes a string, will perform a transformation and return it.
For each of the letters of the parameter string switch it by the next one in alphabetical order.
'z' becomes 'a' and 'Z' becomes 'A'. Case remains unaffected.*

```
def rotone(param_1)
  a = ""
param_1.each_char do |x|
    if x.count("a-zA-Z") > 0
        a << x.succ
    else
        a << x
    end
end
   a
end
```

*And I take this:*

```
Input:  "AkjhZ zLKIJz , 23y "
Expected Return Value: "BlkiA aMLJKa , 23z "
Return Value:          "BlkiAA aaMLJKaa , 23z "
```

***When iterators find 'z' or 'Z' it increment two times z -> aa or Z -> AA***

Comment: Use [`tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-tr), e.g. `str.tr('abcABC', 'bcdBCD')` (you get the idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input = "AkjhZ zLKIJz , 23y"
```

Code

```
p input.tr('a-yA-YzZ','b-zB-ZaA')
```

Output

```
"BlkiA aMLJKa , 23z"
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. But can you explain me what happaned here. What's problem in my code?

Comment: I like. I was wondering how efficient the use of `tr` would be. Upon examining the C code for [tr_trans](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/string.c) (which does most of the work) it appears to be very efficient. For example, if a character `c` of `input` is found to be an ASCII character it will use something like `('a'.ord..'y'.ord).cover?(c.ord)` to see if `c` is in the range `'a'...'y'` (as opposed to merely stepping through the range).

Comment: @Cary Swoveland Thanks for letting me know. Yes it's interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that [String#succ](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-succ) (aka [String#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-next)) has been designed in a way that does not serve your purpose when the receiver is `'z'` or `'Z'`:

```
'z'.succ #=> 'aa'
'Z'.succ #=> 'AA'
```

If you replaced `a << x.succ` with `a << x.succ[0]` you would obtain the desired result.

---

You might consider writing that as follows.

```
def rotone(param_1)
  param_1.gsub(/./m) { |c| c.match?(/[a-z]/i) ? c.succ[0] : c }
end
```

[String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)'s argument is a regular expression that matches every character (so every character is passed to `gsub`'s block)<sup>1</sup>.

See also [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-match). The regular expression `/[a-z]/i` matches every character that is one of the characters in the *character class* `[a-z]`. The option `i` makes the match *case-independent*, so uppercase letters are matched as well.

---

Here is alternative way to write the method that employs two hashes that are defined as constants.

```
CODE = [*'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z'].each_with_object({}) do |c,h|
  h[c] = c.succ[0]
end.tap { |h| h.default_proc = proc { |_h,k| k } }
  #=> {"a"=>"b", "b"=>"c",..., "y"=>"z", "z"=>"a",
  #    "A"=>"B", "B"=>"C",..., "Y"=>"Z", "Z"=>"A"}
```

```
DECODE = CODE.invert.tap { |h| h.default_proc = proc { |_h,k| k } }
  #=> {"b"=>"a", "c"=>"b", ..., "z"=>"y", "a"=>"z",
  #    "B"=>"A", "C"=>"B", ..., "Z"=>"Y", "A"=>"Z"}
```

For example,

```
CODE['e'] #=> "f"
CODE['Z'] #=> "A"
CODE['?'] #=> "?"
```

```
DECODE['f'] #=> "e"
DECODE['A'] #=> "Z"
DECODE['?'] #=> "?"
```

---

Let's try using `gsub`, `CODE` and `DECODE` with an example string.

```
str = "The quick brown dog Zelda jumped over the lazy fox Arnie"

rts = str.gsub(/./m, CODE)
  #=> "Uif rvjdl cspxo eph Afmeb kvnqfe pwfs uif mbaz gpy Bsojf"
```

```
rts.gsub(/./m, DECODE)
  #=> "The quick brown dog Zelda jumped over the lazy fox Arnie"
```

---

See [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge), [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-tap), [Hash#default_proc=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D), [Hash#invert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert) and the form of [Sting#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a hash as its optional second argument.

Adding the *default proc* to the hash `h` causes `h[k]` to return `k` if `h` does not have a key `k`. Had `CODE` been defined without the default proc,

```
CODE = [*'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z'].each_with_object({}) { |c,h| h[c] = c.succ[0] }
  #=> {"a"=>"b", "b"=>"c",..., "y"=>"z", "z"=>"a",
  #    "A"=>"B", "B"=>"C",..., "Y"=>"Z", "Z"=>"A"}
```

`gsub` would skip over characters that are not letters:

```
rts = str.gsub(/./m, CODE)
  #=> "UifrvjdlcspxoephAfmebkvnqfepwfsuifmbazgpyBsojf"
```

Without the default proc we would have to write

```
rts = str.gsub(/./m) { |s| CODE.fetch(s, s) }
  #=> "Uif rvjdl cspxo eph Afmeb kvnqfe pwfs uif mbaz gpy Bsojf"
```

See [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

<sup>1. The regular expression `/./` matches every character other than line terminators. Adding the option `m` (`/./m`) causes `.` to match line terminators as well.</sup>